# Cannot deploy application on Tomcat 7 Due to "invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted " error

Tags: java, tomcat

i've got  aproblem! i'm trying to install my webapp on my tomcat server 7 installation but it keeps on saying that it cannot deploy my app due to "invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted".

here's my catalina log error:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted       ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]] in state [STARTED]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:822)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:765)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:910)
```

I've tryied even to delete manually "myapp" folder and ".war" into tomcat's webapp folder (after turning off tomcat) but it doesn't resolve anything.

i tryied also to redeploy my oldest .war files of the app but it won't start at all.

Someone has got any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your JRE is using different web server vendor servlet api (javax.servlet.*). Try to check your System classpath.

Comment: I solved the problem. 

in my specific case my application, on startup, was searching for a string representing the config file path location contained into its web.xml file that was not present on production enviroment file.

i have also added the scope=provided to my pom.xml as you suggested

    `<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>`