# Migration from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 9

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I am getting this error while running application on tomcat 9.0.13 earlier we used tomcat 7.0.81

Please help me out on this.
In case you need more details please let me know.

**StackTrace**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51392,suspend=y,server=n -Xms512M -Xmx4096M -javaagent:C:\Users\hemantkumar\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar=file:/C:/Users/hemantkumar/AppData/Local/Temp/capture3429.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\TnT\tnt-core\trackntraceserver\target\webapp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\sentinel\common\sentinel-ua\3.11.0-2\sentinel-ua-3.11.0-2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\sentinel\common\sentinel-common-circularbuffer\3.11.0-2\sentinel-common-circularbuffer-3.11.0-2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\sentinel\common\sentinel-common-core\3.11.0-2\sentinel-common-core-3.11.0-2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\axway-tools\1.3.3\axway-tools-1.3.3.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\lib\tools.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\jradius\jradius-client\2.0.0\jradius-client-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\flywaydb\flyway-core\4.0.3\flyway-core-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.4\ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.3.1\commons-cli-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.1\commons-collections4-4.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.4\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-dbutils\commons-dbutils\1.6\commons-dbutils-1.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.3.2\commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.10\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\report\axway-report-engine\1.0.1\axway-report-engine-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\ria\toolkit\ria-toolkit-tools-pojo2as3\2.0\ria-toolkit-tools-pojo2as3-2.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\ws\servlet\2.2.8\servlet-2.2.8.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\ws\rt\2.2.8\rt-2.2.8.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\ws\policy\2.3.1\policy-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.7\jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\2.16\istack-commons-runtime-2.16.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.7\jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.12\FastInfoset-1.2.12.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\gmbal\gmbal-api-only\3.1.0-b001\gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\external\management-api\3.0.0-b012\management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.7.1\stax-ex-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\stream\buffer\streambuffer\1.5.1\streambuffer-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\jvnet\mimepull\mimepull\1.9.1\mimepull-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\codehaus\woodstox\woodstox-core-asl\4.1.2\woodstox-core-asl-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.1\stax2-api-3.1.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\org\apache\xml\internal\resolver\20050927\resolver-20050927.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\xml\ws\rt-ha\2.2.8\rt-ha-2.2.8.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\ha\ha-api\3.1.9\ha-api-3.1.9.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2-b03\javax.annotation-api-1.2-b03.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\jws\jsr181-api\1.0-MR1\jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\jms\jms\1.1\jms-1.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.5.6\javax.mail-1.5.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\4.0.0\javax.servlet-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\log4j\apache-log4j-extras\1.2.17\apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec\1.0\geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec\1.0\geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec\1.0\geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jcdi_1.1_spec\1.0\geronimo-jcdi_1.1_spec-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\openwebbeans\openwebbeans-spi\1.6.2\openwebbeans-spi-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\openwebbeans\openwebbeans-impl\1.6.2\openwebbeans-impl-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\xbean\xbean-finder-shaded\4.3\xbean-finder-shaded-4.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\xbean\xbean-asm5-shaded\4.3\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\openwebbeans\openwebbeans-web\1.6.2\openwebbeans-web-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\openwebbeans\openwebbeans-el22\1.6.2\openwebbeans-el22-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz\2.2.3\quartz-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\c3p0\c3p0\0.9.1.1\c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.12\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.12\slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\tnt\thirdparty\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\org.eclipse.birt.runtime\4.6.0-20160607\org.eclipse.birt.runtime-4.6.0-20160607.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\com.ibm.icu\56.1.0.v201601250100\com.ibm.icu-56.1.0.v201601250100.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda\3.5.0.201603142002\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda-3.5.0.201603142002.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer\3.3.0.201603142002\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer-3.3.0.201603142002.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml\1.3.0.201603142002\org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml-1.3.0.201603142002.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\org.w3c.css.sac\1.3.1.v200903091627\org.w3c.css.sac-1.3.1.v200903091627.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\scout\sdk\deps\org.eclipse.core.runtime\3.12.0.v20160606-1342\org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.12.0.v20160606-1342.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\scout\sdk\deps\org.eclipse.core.jobs\3.8.0.v20160509-0411\org.eclipse.core.jobs-3.8.0.v20160509-0411.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\scout\sdk\deps\org.eclipse.equinox.preferences\3.6.0.v20160120-1756\org.eclipse.equinox.preferences-3.6.0.v20160120-1756.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\org.mozilla.javascript\1.7.5.v201504281450\org.mozilla.javascript-1.7.5.v201504281450.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\scout\sdk\deps\org.eclipse.equinox.registry\3.6.100.v20160223-2218\org.eclipse.equinox.registry-3.6.100.v20160223-2218.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\3_7_1\org.apache.batik.util\1.6.0\org.apache.batik.util-1.6.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\scout\sdk\deps\org.eclipse.equinox.common\3.8.0.v20160509-1230\org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.8.0.v20160509-1230.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\3_7_1\org.apache.batik.css\1.6.0\org.apache.batik.css-1.6.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\scout\sdk\deps\org.eclipse.osgi\3.11.0.v20160603-1336\org.eclipse.osgi-3.11.0.v20160603-1336.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\3_7_1\com.lowagie.text\2.1.7\com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\birt\runtime\3_7_1\org.apache.xerces\2.9.0\org.apache.xerces-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\poi\poi\3.16\poi-3.16.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.16\poi-ooxml-3.16.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\github\virtuald\curvesapi\1.04\curvesapi-1.04.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.16\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\net\sf\jtidy\jtidy\r938\jtidy-r938.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\jgit\org.eclipse.jgit\3.7.1.201504261725-r\org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.50\jsch-0.1.50.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\googlecode\javaewah\JavaEWAH\0.7.9\JavaEWAH-0.7.9.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\flex\blazeds\flex-messaging-common\4.7.3\flex-messaging-common-4.7.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\flex\blazeds\flex-messaging-core\4.7.3\flex-messaging-core-4.7.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\flex\blazeds\flex-messaging-remoting\4.7.3\flex-messaging-remoting-4.7.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\defence\axway-defence\2.0.0-1\axway-defence-2.0.0-1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\2.0.3\jsr305-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fortify\fortify-annotations\1.0\fortify-annotations-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\felix\org.osgi.core\1.4.0\org.osgi.core-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\activemq\activemq-kahadb-store\5.14.1\activemq-kahadb-store-5.14.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\activemq\protobuf\activemq-protobuf\1.1\activemq-protobuf-1.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\commons-net\commons-net\3.5\commons-net-3.5.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\activemq\activemq-broker\5.14.1\activemq-broker-5.14.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\activemq\activemq-client\5.14.1\activemq-client-5.14.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\fusesource\hawtbuf\hawtbuf\1.11\hawtbuf-1.11.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\activemq\activemq-openwire-legacy\5.14.1\activemq-openwire-legacy-5.14.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-server\2.22.2\jersey-server-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-common\2.22.2\jersey-common-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\bundles\repackaged\jersey-guava\2.22.2\jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-jaxb\2.22.2\jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-api\2.4.0-b34\hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-utils\2.4.0-b34\hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\hk2\external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.4.0-b34\aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\hk2\external\javax.inject\2.4.0-b34\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-locator\2.4.0-b34\hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet-core\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\persistence\persistence-api\1.0.2\persistence-api-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-client\2.22.2\jersey-client-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\ext\cdi\jersey-cdi1x\2.22.2\jersey-cdi1x-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fasterxml\jackson\jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider\2.8.6\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fasterxml\jackson\jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-base\2.8.6\jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.6\jackson-core-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.6\jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.8.6\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1-jboss\dom4j-1.6.1-jboss.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\commons\search\commons-search\1.8.0-2\commons-search-1.8.0-2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.1\antlr4-runtime-4.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\abego\treelayout\org.abego.treelayout.core\1.0.1\org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\shiro\shiro-core\1.3.2\shiro-core-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\shiro\shiro-web\1.3.2\shiro-web-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\shiro\shiro-ehcache\1.3.2\shiro-ehcache-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-core\2.5.3\ehcache-core-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\jolbox\bonecp\0.8.0.RELEASE\bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\xml\soap\javax.xml.soap-api\1.3.5\javax.xml.soap-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.7\jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\xml\ws\jaxws-api\2.2.9\jaxws-api-2.2.9.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\santuario\xmlsec\1.5.8\xmlsec-1.5.8.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\jersey\ext\jersey-bean-validation\2.25.1\jersey-bean-validation-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.1.3.Final\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.3.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.0.0\classmate-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\javax\el\javax.el-api\2.2.4\javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\glassfish\web\javax.el\2.2.4\javax.el-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\tools\test\test\1.9.0-1\test-1.9.0-1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\mockito\mockito-core\1.9.5\mockito-core-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.1\hsqldb-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\h2database\h2\1.3.174\h2-1.3.174.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\mongodb\mongo-java-driver\2.11.4\mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\jayway\restassured\rest-assured\2.9.0\rest-assured-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy\2.4.4\groovy-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-xml\2.4.4\groovy-xml-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\ccil\cowan\tagsoup\tagsoup\1.2.1\tagsoup-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\jayway\restassured\json-path\2.9.0\json-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-json\2.4.4\groovy-json-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\jayway\restassured\rest-assured-common\2.9.0\rest-assured-common-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\jayway\restassured\xml-path\2.9.0\xml-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\networknt\json-schema-validator\0.1.2\json-schema-validator-0.1.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\slf4j\slf4j-ext\1.7.21\slf4j-ext-1.7.21.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\ch\qos\cal10n\cal10n-api\0.8.1\cal10n-api-0.8.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\io\undertow\undertow-core\1.4.0.Final\undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\jboss\xnio\xnio-api\3.3.6.Final\xnio-api-3.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\jboss\xnio\xnio-nio\3.3.6.Final\xnio-nio-3.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.4.1\httpclient-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.1\httpcore-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.4.1\httpmime-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\xmlunit\xmlunit\1.4\xmlunit-1.4.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.9.5\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\deltaspike\core\deltaspike-core-api\1.5.2\deltaspike-core-api-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\deltaspike\core\deltaspike-core-impl\1.5.2\deltaspike-core-impl-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\deltaspike\cdictrl\deltaspike-cdictrl-owb\1.5.2\deltaspike-cdictrl-owb-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\deltaspike\cdictrl\deltaspike-cdictrl-api\1.5.2\deltaspike-cdictrl-api-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\deltaspike\modules\deltaspike-test-control-module-api\1.5.2\deltaspike-test-control-module-api-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\deltaspike\modules\deltaspike-test-control-module-impl\1.5.2\deltaspike-test-control-module-impl-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.13\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\9.0.13\tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-logging-juli\9.0.0.M1\tomcat-embed-logging-juli-9.0.0.M1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-jasper\9.0.13\tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.13\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\eclipse\jdt\ecj\3.13.102\ecj-3.13.102.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\9.0.13\tomcat-jasper-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-servlet-api\9.0.13\tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\9.0.13\tomcat-juli-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-el-api\9.0.13\tomcat-el-api-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-api\9.0.13\tomcat-api-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util-scan\9.0.13\tomcat-util-scan-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util\9.0.13\tomcat-util-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper-el\9.0.13\tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jsp-api\9.0.13\tomcat-jsp-api-9.0.13.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\awaitility\awaitility\2.0.0\awaitility-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\cglib\cglib-nodep\3.1\cglib-nodep-3.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\rdops\connectors\qc\notifier\qc-notifier-client\1.4.1-1\qc-notifier-client-1.4.1-1.jar;C:\Users\hemantkumar\.m2\repositoryECD\com\axway\rdops\connectors\qc\notifier\qc-notifier-shared\1.4.1-1\qc-notifier-shared-1.4.1-1.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.axway.tnt.tools.servers.EmbeddedServer
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51392', transport: 'socket'
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Nov 27, 2018 5:51:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
Nov 27, 2018 5:51:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_init]) for component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]] in state [INITIALIZED]
    at com.axway.tnt.tools.servers.EmbeddedServer.start(EmbeddedServer.java:139)
    at com.axway.tnt.tools.servers.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_init]) for component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]] in state [INITIALIZED]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:372)
    at com.axway.tnt.tools.servers.EmbeddedServer.start(EmbeddedServer.java:133)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Did you upgrade to jdk8+ too?

Comment: it's mentioned in apache recommendation, using jdk8

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade?

Comment: we are already using it

Answer (score 4):

The issue is resolved it was because you don't need to use add connector explicitly as setConnector method of tomcat 9 internally adds the connector.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at this previous issue:
[Cannot deploy application on Tomcat 7 Due to "invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted " error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905011/cannot-deploy-application-on-tomcat-7-due-to-invalid-lifecycle-transition-was-a)

The issue is probably unrelated with the upgrade.